# Ubuntu Server and Active Directory group login

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, sshd, active-directory-group

Note: I am neither a Windows or Unix IT guy. Just a unix-familiar software developer working with our windows based IT team.

I have successfully joined an Ubuntu 16.04 server to our Active Directory domain. By that I mean that the computer shows up in the list of domain machines and I can log into the machine using my domain credentials.

I want to use an AD group to restrict who can log into the machine. Most of the examples I have found all have simple names like "Admins".

Our group name is more like ...

> DN: CN=ENG SysAdmin,OU=Groups,OU=DIVISION,DC=CORP,DC=INTRA

Note the spaces in the common name. What steps should I follow to limit access to the members of this group?

Answer (score 0):

When I listed the groups in the system with the **wbinfo -g** command, I noticed that all group names were converted to lower case. So I added the following to **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
AllowGroups "eng sysadmin"
```

I was then able to ssh into the machine using my Active Directory credentials.